# CSS Error while i save my docoment as pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have an HTML page which i used to print data from mysql db.
My code is working fine.

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    font: 12pt "Times New Roman";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        min-height: 297mm;
        padding: 18mm;
        margin: 5mm auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    }
    .subpage {
        padding: 1cm;
        border: 5px solid;
        height: 257mm;
        outline: 2cm #FFEAEA solid;
    }

    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;  
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact    
        }
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
```

**PROBLEM:**

When i give command to print and select save as pdf then my one page document is convert into two pages and second page is blank.

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Just remove `page-break-after: always;`?

Comment: @OopsD'oh Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: Avoid;}
}
```